# Python Pandas DataFrame Rounding of big fraction values

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

How to round off big fraction values of a pandas DataFrame.I want to round off the "Gaps between male and female score" column of the given Dataframe image. I have tried following:

```
df.astype('int').round()
```

but it doesn't work?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19DTn.png)

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].round()`

Comment: [enter image description here](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/2f94e15d-6762-45f5-8a3d-acc4e454b9b3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering some initial rows of your dataframe,

```
    Year    Score
0   1990    1.00378
1   1992    2.37824
2   2000    2.51302
3   2003    2.96111
```

Now, if you want to `round` score to `int`, do this,

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
    Year    Score
0   1990    1
1   1992    2
2   2000    2
3   2003    2
```

And, if you want to round upto some decimal digits say upto 2-digits.
Note: you can round upto as many digits as you want by passing required value to `round()`.

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].round(2)
df
```

Output:

```
  Year  Score
0   1990    1.00
1   1992    2.38
2   2000    2.51
3   2003    2.96
```

If you want to round by `ceil` or by `floor`, then use `np.ceil(series)` or `np.floor(series)` respectively.

Comment: @Avijit Saha please accept this `answer` if it worked!

Comment: Please refrain from harassing the OP to accept your answer, especially to a question like this. You can wait 24 hours, and then write a follow up comment under the question.

Comment: thanks a lot Abdur Rehman

Comment: @coldspeed got it. Thanks for guiding.